# Missing "Add to Wishlist" button after I tried to add a game to wishlist and got "Oops sorry!"

Tags: steam

This has happened several times, but I've just realized that this weird "Oops sorry!" message seems to be causing it.

Here is the most recent case I'm facing with Hawken. I tried adding the game to my Wishlist, but failed. It displayed the message "Oops sorry!" for a moment. I refreshed the page, and the button disappeared.

[image]

I checked my Wishlist page, just in case it's been there. But unfortunately the game has not been added to my Wishlist either.

This has happened several times and it's quite annoying.

Anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the client, or the web? Have you tried restarting Steam? You can probably do it via the web, as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Why do you want to add a free to play game to your wishlist? It's already as on sale as it's going to be. Is this occurring with other games?

Comment: Does this happen with all games or just this one?

Comment: If you own the game you cannot add it anymore...

Comment: @Gerret I haven't own the game. It says "You already own Hawken" because it's a free to play game.

Comment: @ver aman207 this happens with several games. Another one I can recall at the moment is Warframe and Borderlands 2. I have tried restarting Steam and logging in from both the client and the web. Still the same.

Comment: @Unionhawk I added this to my wishlist just for a reminder to myself. I don't have sufficient space on my hard drive at this time...

Comment: @deathlock This is not true. I looked F2P games up and I am able to add them to my wishlist. You cannot add the game hawken because you own it already (you probably have clicked one time on the "buy" button and may also downloaded it at any time).

Comment: @Gerret: well, that's your experience. My experience says otherwise. But you mentioned a good point - I never downloaded the game, but there was a time that the game appeared in my game library without my consideration (what is that called? promotion?), asking me to install the game. That might be the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be that the game you picked is free to play. It doesn't need to be bought, so there is little reason to add it to your wish list.

However, a more useful error message would definitely be in order. You might want to report this as a bug to Valve.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason I added it to my wishlist is because I tend to forget a lot. So my wishlist serves as my personal reminder. I'd love to report this as a bug, do you know the link?